# When I compile and run; which it does perfectly fine; it is not outputting anything to the file named "Warframe_Weapons_Sheet." in the code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Variables
string Weapon_Name = "undefined";
string Weapon_Type_Name = "undefined";
bool Weapon_Type_M_or_R = false;

int main(int args, char * argv[])
{

    cout << "Input the weapon name." << endl;
    cin >> Weapon_Name;

    cout << "Confirm weapon type." << endl;
    cin >> Weapon_Type_Name;

    cout << "Is weapon melee or range? true or false." << endl;
    cin >> Weapon_Type_M_or_R;
```

The if statement on line 24 as well as the code block that follows is where I first ask the boolean for melee(true) and range(false) is true, which is then followed by
me creating the file stream object "Warframe_Weapons_Sheet". I then open a .csv file I created and then input a string to the ofstream object which is followed by inputting variables that contain string values.

```
    if (Weapon_Type_M_or_R = true) {

    ofstream MyExcelFile("Warframe_Weapons_Sheet");
    MyExcelFile.open("C:/Users/A12st/Downloads/Warframe_Melee_Weapons_Sheet.csv");
    MyExcelFile << "Weapon Name, Weapon Type" << endl;
    MyExcelFile << Weapon_Name << "," << Weapon_Type_Name << endl;
    MyExcelFile.close();

  } else {

      ofstream MyExcelFile("Warframe_Weapons_Sheet");
      MyExcelFile.open("C:/Users/A12st/Downloads/Warframe_Ranged_Weapons_Sheet.csv");
      MyExcelFile << "Weapon Name, Weapon Type" << endl;
      MyExcelFile << Weapon_Name << "," <<  Weapon_Type_Name << endl;
      MyExcelFile.close();

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `ofstream MyExcelFile("Warframe_Weapons_Sheet");` to just be `ofstream MyExcelFile;` and see what happens.

Comment: `ofstream MyExcelFile("Warframe_Weapons_Sheet");` opens the file `Warframe_Weapons_Sheet` for writing so there is nothing wrong with that. But, in your code, there is one `open()` call that follows immediately after the construction of `MyExcelFile` and opens a different file, which overwrites the previous `open()` call invoked by the constructor of the object, so your data will be written to  `C:/Users/A12st/Downloads/Warframe_Ranged_Weapons_Sheet.csv` instead.

Comment: `if (Weapon_Type_M_or_R = true)` does not do what you think it does. Furthermore, the fact that both the `if` and the `else` portion appears to be identical doesn't help things, either.

Comment: If you remove unnecessary details from your code, the culprit might find itself out of places to hide. Don't try to keep your intended functionality; your only goal is to keep the malfunction. For starters, don't rely on user input. Simplify as much as you can to get a [mre]. (If the error spotted by Sam Varshavchik is the one you are asking about, your simplified example might be `int main() { bool Weapon_Type_M_or_R = false; if (Weapon_Type_M_or_R = true) { std::cout << "Got true.\n"; } else { std::cout << "Got false.\n"; } }`. If the bug is something else, you probably don't need the `if`.)

Comment: I'm sorry, if all of this is obvious to you guys because I'm still a beginner in C++. As for what Sam Varshavchick said, melee is supposed to be the true value, and range is supposed to be the false value. If there are only two options to choose between then I can use a boolean, no?

Comment: *"I'm sorry, if all of this is obvious to you"* -- actually, I found several parts of this question to be not obvious, because the explanation is inadequate. A good question would have a simple code example focused on the line that is not behaving as you expect, and there would be a clear statement (in the question, not in the title) of what the expected and actual results are. (Ideally, this is presented abstractly, removing the need to know what your full program does.) In your question, it is not clear what your symptom is, so it is difficult to pick out which of your errors is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if (Weapon_Type_M_or_R = true) {` should read `if (Weapon_Type_M_or_R == true) {`
The first is assigning a value of true to the variable and then "evaluating" that expression. The second is comparing the variable to the constant `true` which is what you want. Also note that if you are comparinf to true you can simply write `if (Weapon_Type_M_or_R) {`

You did not open any file by that name. As comments have suggested you opened "C:/Users/A12st/Downloads/Warframe_Ranged_Weapons_Sheet.csv" for writing instead. Check that file for your output.

Also keep in mind that since you did not explcitly declare it, you are using the default mode of out. Everytime your program opens that file it will be completely rewritten. To append instead, try

```
ofstream MyExcelFile("Warframe_Weapons_Sheet",std::ofstream::app);
```

Check
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/

Comment: Thanks for answering. How would I change the default mode of out?

Comment: Also, I had an if statement that said if the value was true it would write data to one file, and if false would write data to a different file. I'm glad it actually outputs, but I'd like to know how to switch between two different files to output to.

Comment: I would create the ofstream object before the if statement with a blank constructor ofstream File(); and then call open on the file that you actually want.

Comment: I don't know if you're still here but it's still not outputting to the excel file I have set up.